# How to avoid repetition of select control values in multiple select controls?

Tags: html, jquery, html-table, html-select

I've a jsFiddle link as follows:

http://jsfiddle.net/gHJ4B/1/

Here I'm adding and deleting the table rows and it's working fine for me. Now what I want to achieve is suppose if user adds three rows to the table. From first select control user selects option `Prosecco` then in the next Product select control that value should not appear. Other three remaining values should appear. Now in second Product select control if user selects option `Tea` then in subsequent product select controls only two remaining value should appear. This should be done in same fashion for the no. of rows added by user. When there are no more products to display then in the remaining product select controls the the message **No Product** should get displayed and selected. How to achieve this?

The HTML code is as follows:

```
<table   id="blacklistgrid"  class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                      <thead>
                        <tr  id="Row1">
                          <th style="vertical-align:middle">Products</th>
                          <th style="vertical-align:middle">Pack Of</th>
                          <th style="vertical-align:middle">Quantity</th>
                          <th style="vertical-align:middle">Volume</th>
                          <th style="vertical-align:middle">Unit</th>
                          <th style="vertical-align:middle">Rebate Amount</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody class="apnd-test">
                                                <tr id="reb1">
                          <td>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                              <select class="form-control prod_list" name="product_id"><option selected="selected" value="">
      Select Product
    </option><option value="8">
      Laptop an
    </option><option value="9">
      Prosecco
    </option><option value="10">
      Coffee
    </option><option value="11">
      Tea
    </option></select>
                            </div>
                          </td>
                          <td><input type="text" name="pack" id="pack" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                          <td><input type="text" name="quantity" id="quantity" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                          <td><input type="text" name="volume" id="volume" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/></td>
                          <td>
                            <div class="btn-group">
                              <select id="units" name="units" class="form-control">
                                <option value=""  selected='selected'>Select Unit</option>

                                <option value="5" >Microsecond</option>

                                <option value="7" >oz</option>

                                <option value="9" >ml</option>

                                <option value="10" >L</option>

                                <option value="12" >gms</option>
                                                               </select>
                            </div>
                          </td>
                          <td><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value="" class="form-control" size="9"/></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                      <tfoot>
                        <tr id="reb2">
                          <td><button style="float:right; margin-bottom: 20px" class="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="">&nbsp;Add</button></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                          <td></td>
                        </tr>
                      </tfoot>

                    </table>
```

The jQuery code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.btnAdd').click(function () {
    var new_row = $('#reb1').clone();
    var tbody = $('tbody', '#blacklistgrid');
    var n = $('tr', tbody).length  + 1;
    new_row.attr('id', 'reb' + n);
    $(':input', new_row).not('.prod_list').remove();
    //new_row.find("td:eq(1)").html();
    $('<button style="color:#C00; opacity: 2;" type="button" class="close delete" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>').appendTo( $(new_row.find('td:first')) );
    tbody.append(new_row);
    $('.delete').on('click', deleteRow);
   });    
    });

function deleteRow() {
  $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut('fast', function(){
    $(this).remove();
 });   
}
```

Comment: Why don't you post code here, in question???  EDIT: thx! ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff:I've added the code now.

Answer (score 0):

You can only achieve this by binding the options of row i+1 to the selected values of rows 1..i.  (Yes I count 1-based here)

Note that the constraint of row i will *depend on the values of the previous rows*, which is both complicated to specify and to program, and not really intuitive to use.

What will happen, for instance, when user selects Prosecco in row 1, Tea in row 2, and then changes his mind and selects Tea in row 1?  Will the selection of row 2 disappear?  What then with rows 3 and 4?...

A question is: do you want that behavior?  Is there a better way to present 4 options to the user?